# Where exactly is the GPS position located on a GPS device?

Tags: coordinate-system, gps, accuracy

I have a very precise GPS which in theory when using RTK achieves 2cm accuracy when reporting its GPS position. But where exactly on the GPS device is this position? In other words, when the GPS device says it is at lat = X, lon = Y, where is this point? At the base of the antenna, the end of the cable, the middle of the antenna?

I have the GPS antenna mounted on a cart. The antenna is around 20 cm + 40 cm cable. In previous mapping scenarios I had to make the mapping with an accuracy of 1 meter, so there was no issue. At this moment I have to do the mapping with 5 cm accuracy and therefore the size of the antenna and the cables may be relevant.

Comment: Should be explained in the manual (of the device or the additional antenna) if it is a precise GPS. There should be a chapter about the correct handling.

Comment: of course on the antenna, you can refer to the manufacture manual. Also, some factors play a role in the position and the accuracy such as (antenna type, antenna placement position)

Comment: What equipment are you using?

Comment: I've also seen antennas that have the data collection point marked right on the casing. If the antenna is round, the data collection point is almost certainly in the center of that circle.